# Access Blocked: Authorization Error[Error 400: invalid_request]

Tags: android, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, google-signin

Configured my React Native App with **OAuth Consent Screen** for Google Sign In.
But, it is showing error when trying to sign in with Sign In button.

```
Access blocked: Authorization Error

....@gmail.com

You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Learn more about this error
If you are a developer of CodeBox(App Name), see error details.
Error 400: invalid_request
```

Followed the steps:

- Go to OAuth Consent Screen -> User Type “External” -> App Name “CodeBox” -> mail-id
- For Android Client Id = Go to Credentials -> OAuth client ID -> Application Type “Android” -> Give package Name ("package": "com.panditsamik.codebox”) -> SHA-1 certificate fingerprint -> Create
- For Web Client Id:  Go to Credentials -> OAuth client ID -> Application Type “Web Application” -> Name -> Authorized Javascript Origins(https://auth.expo.io) -> Authorized redirect URIs(https://auth.expo.io/@username/codebox)

In app.json,

```
"expo": {
    "name": "education-app",
    "slug": "codebox",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scheme": "codebox",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
.
.
.
```

In Login.js component, When Sign In with Google button was clicked, it was showing error of **Access Blocked: Authorization Error[Error 400: invalid_request]**

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Image,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import Colors from "../Shared/Colors";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import * as WebBrowser from "expo-web-browser";
import * as Google from "expo-auth-session/providers/google";

export default function Login() {
  WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    androidClientId:
      "....apps.googleusercontent.com",
    expoClientId:
      "....apps.googleusercontent.com",
  });
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Image
        source={require("./../Assets/Images/login.png")}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}
      />
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.textStyle} numberOfLines={2}>
          Welcome to Education App
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login/SignUp</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => promptAsync()}>
          <FontAwesome name="google" size={24} color="white" />
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Sign In with Google</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

As a solution I got *You have to make sure you added the callback url and all inside google cloud console*

I just checked it through ChatGPT which says **"Ensure that the authorized redirect URIs in your Google Cloud Console configuration match the redirect URI you are using in your app's OAuth code."**

The authorized redirect URI in Expo Client ID is (https://auth.expo.io/@username/codebox).
The authorized domain in the OAuth consent screen settings is expo.io
Still, it is not working.